# ORB feature tracking in opencv 3.0/c++

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking, feature-detection, orb

The following link is about ORB  detection and matching between two images:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/features2d/akaze_tracking/akaze_tracking.html?highlight=orb%20akaze

However, it is not clear how to follow the same procedure for tracking. In details, for each new frame I would perform

`matcher.match(descriptors[0], descriptors[1], matches);`
... then extract good matches.

The question is how to obtain/build `descriptors[0]` from `keypoints[0]`, which has been previously exracted from `matches` (good matches)?

P.S. am interested in orb-orb detection and tracking, since it is claimed that it provides a good compromise  between speed and accuracy/robustness.

Comment: detector->detectAndCompute(frame, noArray(), kp, desc) is the function that extracts the keypoints and build the descriptor from the detected keypoints.

Comment: @HaDang For tracking, I need to keep the same keepoints. The command you present will substitute the keypoints with new ones, and thus the tracking would be lost. In fact, I need to track the same (physical) point for a certain time span. `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` affords this, but how to do it with ORB?

Comment: well then, IMHO, you just need to run matcher.match(descriptors[0], descriptors[n], matches) where n is the description of the n-th frame where you want to track your original points (i.e. descriptors[0]).